# Is there a way how to convert live powerBi connection to import data?

Tags: powerbi

I have a powerBI report that connects live to a SQL Analysis Server where it gets data. I'd like to have the data as import data instead of live connection. Is there any way how to convert this report so that it doesn't use the live connection but downloads the data and uses that instead, without doing it manually ? The report is quite big and also the data is huge so it's very time consuming doing it manually. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Switching from Live connection to Import mode currently is not supported. You can [vote](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/18556393-support-switching-ssas-connect-model-from-connect) for this idea, if you want to. You should create a new report and copy/paste as much as possible from your existing report.

Comment: So you suggest downloading the data from SSAS and then recreate the report with imported data if I understood correctly ?

Comment: Recreating the report from scratch, but this time importing the data, in practice is your only option. If you can copy/paste some visuals and measures from your original report, it will be good for you!